# Autocomplete always stays on, how to make disappear with mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am having issues with jquery-autocomplete

if i start typing then the results / suggestions would show.. but i want to be able to have then disappear when someone clicks somewhere else on the page, and if possible when the user hits escape.

thanks in advance.

i would like it to work like the tags textbox when submitting this question.

:D

Comment: You could try looking at the JavaScript code for the tags textbox, if that's how you want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on particular plugin you're using, but two most popular autocomplete pluging for jquery have that functionality by default. Check yourself.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete

Comment: that made it work... i guess i had an older version

thanks a lot

Comment: question.. how do i make the list result longer... id rather now show the vertical side scroll bar.. 
is there an easy config section where i can set it?

thanks

Comment: @sala Yes, there should be an option for that in docs. But first, which of two plugins are you using?

Comment: @sala They are different unrelated plugins written by different people and not sharing any sources. So, you should choose the one you want and check its API. For example, first one has the list of options here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions